# Meteor 0.8 release and findOne

Tags: meteor

Meteor 0.8 just released and some of the findOne calls I had in working code stopped working. The documentation still shows it there, so am assuming it has not be deprecated.  Anybody else having this problem?

Comment: Posting code helps people help you.  Click edit and copy/paste it in.

Answer (score 0):

Had some issues with findOne, so I switched to find after finding this article:

https://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/

It's a year old post, but I'm unsure if they've actually changed the behavior. I would suggest substituting all your instances of findOne with a find + limit(1) and see if that fixes the issue.